# Domain on Integration Based on 2 Conditions

Tags: calculus, integration, curves

I need to figure out the domain of integration for the expression $\int \int dx_1 dx_2$. The answer should come from the two constraints below:

$$ x_1 + x_2 = 1- \frac{\mu^2}{s}$$

And

$$ (1 - x_1)(1 - x_2) = \frac{\mu^2}{s} $$

The final answer is

$$\int_{0}^{1-\frac{\mu^2}{s}}dx_1 \int_{1-x_1-\frac{\mu^2}{s}}^{1 - \frac{t}{s(1-x_1)}}dx_2$$

I am not sure what $t$ is, but I do not care.

Here’s what I’ve done. I assumed that the two curves given by the conditions coincide at some points. Using this I was able to find that $x_1$ does in fact have two solutions: $0$ and $1-\frac{\mu^2}{s}$, which I guess explains the first integral. I need now to understand the boundaries of the second integral.

Can anybody please help?

Comment: Should those constraints be inequalities?

Comment: No, they’re in fact correct as written.

Comment: Then you're integrating for the region bounded by those two curves?

Comment: Yes (I guess). The question reads *Find the region of integration for $x_1$ and $x_2$ for [the above conditions]*.